# Loop in an algorithm which is dependent on hex value

Tags: c, algorithm, for-loop, cryptography, cryptanalysis

I am only learning c and I am trying to implement a for loop from an algorithm. I am so so confused in how to implement it, please see my attempt below. Any help or thoughts would be greatly appreciated, it implies a loop within a loop which has a dependency to hex value. It has come from an Differential Cryptanalysis algorithm.

the loop as stated in algorithm is :

[image]

[image]

ciphertext C0 = (L0,R0) 
 ciphertext C1 = (L1,R1)

Where

```
                long long c0 = 0x78661EB54FE76763;
                long long c1 = 0x98D9EC2327F1BF03;
```

My attempt so far

```
                long long c0 = 0x78661EB54FE76763;
                long long c1 = 0x98D9EC2327F1BF03;

                for (int c0 = 0; c0 <= 0xff; c0++)
                {
                    for (int c1 = 0; c1 <= 0xff; c1++)
                    {
                    }
                }
```

But I dont know how to handle the depenacy to hex values. Its is latter ordering: (0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 2), ..., (0, 255), (1, 0), …

So it means all possible combinations - the ordering does not matter so long as you go through them all.

Comment: What is the question? Your loops seem to be correct ...

Comment: if you look at the for loop in the image, it shows a dependency to two cipher text values, in there complete form, so the questain is how can one write a loop in the context of hex values

Comment: You could look at the stuff inside the loop and figure out whether it depends on the order, or you could read the text surrounding the algorithm and it might tell you.

Comment: Note `c1` is likely initialize as negative.  Suggest using `unsigned long long`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lack of context made it difficult to understand your question. Looking at [it](https://books.google.com/books?id=bF9GDgAAQBAJ&pg=PA178) reveals that the problem lies in *D = (c<sub>0</sub>, a<sub>0</sub> ⊕ c<sub>0</sub>, a<sub>1</sub> ⊕ c<sub>1</sub>, c<sub>1</sub>)*, i. e. you need to know how to make a 32-bit value out of a 4-tuple of 8-bit values. This can be done simply by shifting the values to the corresponding positions:

```
                for (int c0 = 0; c0 <= 0xff; c0++)
                    for (int c1 = 0; c1 <= 0xff; c1++)
                    {
                        uint32_t D = c0<<24|(a0^c0)<<16|(a1^c1)<<8|c1;
                        …
                    }
```